# Are theme .php files stored in the database?

Tags: themes, database, https

I'm asking about the relation of WP .php files (themes etc.) with the database. Is (part of) the content of these files stored in any way on the database?

**Context:**
I'm trying to migrate from http to https. All the relevant guides, talk exclusively about a "Search and Replace" of the http://domain with the https://domain in the database. Nowhere did I find anyone mention that you should also do a search and replace in the theme or other .php files of WP; though often there are links/references to the domain in these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a theme's `.php` files are not stored in the database. Themes *should not* be hardcoding URLs in their files. However, it's totally possible for this to happen, particularly with a custom theme or plugins whose developer did not follow best practices.

I'd suggest using a search utility such as grep ([grepwin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) is nice for Windows) to look within your files just to be sure if your domain appears or not.

Also, when doing a search and replace on the DB, remember to use a utility that is able to handle serialized arrays, since a simple string replacement will damage data. [WP CLI's search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) is one option. [WP DB Migrate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) is really nice too.

Be sure to make a backup of everything before you make changes.